# Difference proxy URL / proxy IP

Tags: url, proxy, urllib

I want to use a proxy server with python 3s urllib.

However in the guides I found they use:
Proxy websites in the form:

```
my-proxy.com:8080
```

While online I mainly find: 
Proxy IPs in the form:

```
106.38.251.63:8088
```

What is the difference? Can I use both or only one?

Answer (score 0):

Its haven't diffrence.

my-proxy.com:8080 is actually 104.27.180.197:8080